# Document height not getting full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I have an black overlay that's going over the page, however it always seems to end at the viewport bottom of the browser, not the bottom of the page.

I'm using

```
$(document).height();
```

This is being called AFTER *$(document).ready()* Which is consoling 1115 on my page, but in reality the page goes as high as 1200.

I've tried, window, innerHeight. All are reporting the same.

I have a feeling it's not waiting for an image to load, which is high. But, not sure a way round if that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it inside `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`

See this [link](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)